# Utilizar variable fuera de ciclo for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, bucle-for, scope

Estoy tratando de llenar un arreglo utilizando la funcion 'push' dentro de un ciclo for, pero al llamar el arreglo fuera del ciclo sigue estando vacio.

Podrian ayudarme a entender como funciona esta parte.

```
app.get('/ReturnStatus', function(request, response) {
 var content = []
 fs.readdirSync(Folder).forEach(function(file) {
    fs.readFile(Folder+file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
                parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                    content.push(result)
            });
        }
    });
});
 response.json(content);
});
```

Comment: y estás completamente seguro de que está llegando hasta el push?

Comment: es posible que no este entrando al la condición if (!err)
revisa si esta entrando a las diferentes funciones apicales un console.log() en cada paso

Comment: Si imprime el arreglo con contenido hasta esa parte, fuera del ciclo imprime un arreglo vacio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando aca es simple, el porgrama estaria leyendo todos los directorios de manera trabante con la funcion `readdirSync`, pero al mandar a leer cada archivo individualmente con la funcion `readFile` esta abriendo tareas asyncronicas, que no espera para devolver el resultado. La solucion a este problema seria reemplazar la llamada a `readFile` por su suplente sincronico `readFileSync`:

```
app.get('/ReturnStatus', function(request, response) {
    var content = []
     fs.readdirSync(Folder).forEach(function(file) {
        fs.readFileSync(Folder+file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                        content.push(result)
                });
            }
        });
    });
    response.json(content);
});
```

**NOTA:** no especificaste de donde viene el objeto parser, este toma una funcion de callback, por lo cual es muy posible que esta tambien deba ser reemplazada por un sustituto sincronico.

Comment: Cambie la funcion readFileSync y si ayudo, ya que el cliente esta recibiendo respuesta, el problema es que sigue siendo vacia.

Al imprimir el arreglo dentro del if, si imprime el arreglo con contenido, pero al llamarlo fuera del ciclo lo imprime vacio, por lo tanto el response esta vacio.

El objeto parser es de la clase xml2js
      var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

Comment: Ahi lo busque, la funcion parseString tampoco es trabante, por lo tanto el push se esta haciendo de manera asincronica

Comment: Excelente, me tomare el tiempo de resolver eso.
Gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Encontre este thread https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/issues/159, puntualmente es una cuestion curiosa, pero al final hay alguien que sugiere usar el `fast-xml-parser`  en su lugar

Comment: Muchas gracias :)